# Locust - retry certain status code but default-handle all others

Tags: python, locust

I have a Locust task that might end up in a 401 if my access token expires. In that case I will renew it and then retry the task. This works all perfectly (based on [this](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#validating-responses)):

```
@task
def list_claims(self):
    with self.client.get("/api/1.0/claim/", name="LIST claims", headers=self.headers, catch_response=True) as response:
        if response.status_code == 401:
            logging.info("401 - Need to fetch a new access token!") # usually happens when the access tokens expires after an hour
            self.aad_b2c_auth()
            raise RescheduleTaskImmediately() # re-run this task with the newly refreshed token
```

The problem is that this seems to suck up all other status codes, so the task will never show up as failed, even it it, for example, returns a 503 etc. I assume that's because of the `catch_response=True`?! So ideally I would only like to special-handle the 401 and leave the rest to the default handler (2xx = success, 4xx/5xx = failure). Is there a built-in way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just add an `else` statement after your 401 check and fire off the request event. An example of that can be seen [here](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html) in the context of manually firing request events when testing other systems. The API documented [here](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.request). Essentially just something like this should work:

```
else:
    environment.events.request.fire(**response.request_meta)
```

Alternatively, you could try marking the request has not having a manual result and Locust might do the firing for you.

```
else:
    response._manual_result = False
```

Not sure if doing it this way is technically supported so it may not always function properly and thus could require additional maintenance down the road.

Comment: thanks I'll give this a try `environment.events.request.fire`